# Trying to Remove quotation marks from integer after using json_encode

Tags: arrays, json

I have make multidimensional array in php and use json encode as:

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

It gives me output as:

```
[["Angies list","10"],["AVVO","15"],["BBB","20"],["Citysearch","25"]]
```

I want to make it as:

```
[["Angies list",10],["AVVO",15],["BBB",20],["Citysearch",25]]
```

Means want to retrieve the integers without commas, how would it be done?
Thanks.

Comment: For your information: these symbols are called "quotation marks" ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` will produce those quotation marks when the data type of the value is a string. If you want to avoid those quotation marks, then you should make sure the data type of those values is really number, not a string that represents a number.

Probably you should change this at the source of the data, but if not, you can change the data type of your array like this (before `json_encode`):

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    $row[1] = intval($row[1]);
}
```

Now when you execute `json_encode` it will be like you wanted it.

Comment: Thanks for your information.. and solving my problem.